# Listview item formatting by content

Tags: java, android

I would like to format a `ListView` entry based on its content. I would like to find any elements in my `ListView` that contain the text "No", and do the following things to the element:

- Center the text
- Make the background of this element a color, say #000000

How would I go about doing this? Could you use something like the following?

```
if((String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(something)==("No")) {Do something};
```

Comment: Are you using an `ArrayAdapter` or a custom Adapter?

Comment: @matiash I'm using an ArrayAdapter

Comment: Just override `getView` in the adapter!

Comment: You can by overriding `getView()` but I hope that isn't really how you plan on comparing `String`s

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned using an `ArrayAdapter`, you should extend the `ArrayAdapter` class and override the `getView` method to conditionally return views the way you want them to be formatted. So, in order to format views specifically containing the text "No", do something similar to the following:

```
View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
TextView t = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_text_view);
if (t.getText().toString().equals("No")) {
    // center the text and set bg color
}
return v;
```

Also, just in case the id of your text view will change in the future, you could override the constructors to save the id of the `TextView` in a field and use it in place of the hard-coded id.

Comment: Wait..where is your `TextView` coming from? I was talking about a `ListView`

Comment: An `ArrayAdapter` uses `TextView`s to populate the `ListView`.